# Как достать код страницы с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Как достать код страницы с помощью JS?
В Python это делается так:

```
r1 = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/')
print(r1.text)
```

Так как же реализовать такое на JS? Спасибо!

Comment: ajax get запрос

Comment: Вам нужно это делать из браузера или из Node. js?

Answer (score 1):

Вы скорее всего не сможете получить код страницы с произвольного домена средствами Javascript в современных браузерах. Это связано с междоменной политикой (cross-domain policy), которая, в свою очередь, означает, что с помощью клиентского скрипта (например javascript) вы не можете запрашивать данные из другого домена, если этот домен запрещает это.

Раньше можно было использовать jQuery.ajax() для выполнения междоменного запроса JSONP. Но эту технологию уже начали удалять из современных браузеров.

Если междоменная политика домена, с которого вы хотите загрузить страницу, разрешает вам это делать, то данные можно легко загрузить, например, с помощью JQuery:

```
jQuery.get("http://www.example.com/").done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
}).fail(function() {
  alert('ошибка');
});
```

Имейте в виду, [эта функция](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) асинхронная, в отличие от синхронной, которую вы применяете в Python.

Если междоменная политика блокирует загрузку, то можно поступить так: ваш клиент (javascript) делает запрос к вашему серверу, ваш сервер скачивает данные с другого сервера и возвращает их вашему клиенту. Такая техника называется Ajax-Proxy.

Comment: А каким образом можно записать данные в переменную?

Comment: alert($( "#news__topnews-1_tab_custom" ).load( "https://yandex.ru/" )); это как то не так

Comment: а jQuery.load('yandex.ru'); пишет jQuery is not a func , хотя jQ подключен

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, или в общем виде здесь: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

по сути получение кода страницы это будет обычный get запрос на любую ссылку. Вопрос только в том даст ли cross-domain policy это сделать, ну и стоит учесть то что если там фронтенд фрейворк то все дерево формируется после запроса поэтому по сути вы получите пустой body